# One Char is Two Bytes in Java?

Tags: java, string, char, byte

In java, one char is two bytes.

But, why below code return 2, not 4?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] b = new String(new char[] {'H', 'I' }).getBytes();
        System.out.println(b.length);

}
```

Comment: JavaDoc (Java 8) says: "Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array. " - What is your platform's default charset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBytes()` encodes the Unicode characters in the default `Charset` of the JVM, usually `ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-8`, both of which uses a single byte to store those characters.

This code should help illustrate what's going on:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test("ISO-8859-1", new char[] { 'H', 'I' });
    test("UTF-8"     , new char[] { 'H', 'I' });
    test("UTF-16LE"  , new char[] { 'H', 'I' });
    test("UTF-32LE"  , new char[] { 'H', 'I' });
    test("ISO-8859-1", new char[] { '⅓', '⅔' });
    test("UTF-8"     , new char[] { '⅓', '⅔' });
    test("UTF-16LE"  , new char[] { '⅓', '⅔' });
    test("UTF-32LE"  , new char[] { '⅓', '⅔' });
    test("UTF-8"     , "");
    test("UTF-16LE"  , "");
    test("UTF-32LE"  , "");
}
static void test(String charsetName, char[] chars) throws Exception {
    test(charsetName, new String(chars));
}
static void test(String charsetName, String input) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = input.getBytes(charsetName);
    System.out.printf("%-12s %-6s", charsetName, new String(bytes, charsetName));
    for (byte b : bytes)
        System.out.printf(" %02x", b);
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
ISO-8859-1   HI     48 49
UTF-8        HI     48 49
UTF-16LE     HI     48 00 49 00
UTF-32LE     HI     48 00 00 00 49 00 00 00
ISO-8859-1   ??     3f 3f
UTF-8        ⅓⅔     e2 85 93 e2 85 94
UTF-16LE     ⅓⅔     53 21 54 21
UTF-32LE     ⅓⅔     53 21 00 00 54 21 00 00
UTF-8           f0 9f 98 80 f0 9f 91 8d
UTF-16LE        3d d8 00 de 3d d8 4d dc
UTF-32LE        00 f6 01 00 4d f4 01 00
```